# How to format JSON data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on Google Chart to render Area chart on 'UI' I have a JSON  Data from my back-end which is not exactly the same i want to format that data into required JSON format from JavaScript end.

so here is my JSON which i am getting from my back-end

```
     [
      [
        "JAYANAGAR",
        "2018-09-01",
        "476426"
      ],
      [
        "MALLESHWARAM",
        "2018-09-01",
        "92141"
      ],
      [
        "KOLAR",
        "2018-09-01",
        "115313"
      ],
      [
        "JAYANAGAR",
        "2018-09-02",
        "511153"
      ],
      [
        "MALLESHWARAM",
        "2018-09-02",
        "115704"
      ],
      [
        "KOLAR",
        "2018-09-02",
        "83597"
      ],
      [
        "JAYANAGAR",
        "2018-09-03",
        "167421"
      ],
      [
        "KOLAR",
        "2018-09-03",
        "53775"
      ]
    ]

what I am trying to achieve is J SON like THIS

    [
  [
    "Billdate",
    "Jayanagar",
    "Malleshwaram",
    "Kolar"
  ],
  [
    "01-09-2018",
    "476426",
    "92141",
    "115313"
  ],
  [
    "02-09-2018",
    "511153",
    "115704",
    "83597"
  ],
  [
    "03-09-2018",
    "167421",
    "0",
    "53775"
  ]
]
```

**What i have done till now is**

```
    let formatData = function (data) {
                    let billdates = [];
                    let outlets = [];
                    data.forEach(element => {
                        if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
                            billdates.push(element.billdate);
                        }
                        if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
                            outlets.push(element.outlet);
                        }
                    });
                    return {
                        data: data,
                        billdates: billdates,
                        outlets: outlets,

                    };
                };
 let renderCHart = function (data) {
                    billdates = data.billdates;
                    outlets = data.outlets;
                    data = data.data;
```

By doing this i have all the billdates outlets and amounts independently but not getting any ideas how to do it further

Expected outcome I want:

```js
const raw =      [
       [
         "JAYANAGAR",
         "2018-09-01",
         "476426"
       ],
       [
         "MALLESHWARAM",
         "2018-09-01",
         "92141"
       ],
       [
         "KOLAR",
         "2018-09-01",
         "115313"
       ],
       [
         "JAYANAGAR",
         "2018-09-02",
         "511153"
       ],
       [
         "MALLESHWARAM",
         "2018-09-02",
         "115704"
       ],
       [
         "KOLAR",
         "2018-09-02",
         "83597"
       ],
       [
         "JAYANAGAR",
         "2018-09-03",
         "167421"
       ],
       [
         "KOLAR",
         "2018-09-03",
         "53775"
       ]
     ]
 let types = new Set();
 const rawObj= raw.reduce((memo, [type, date, value]) => {
   date = date.split('-').reverse().join('-');
   memo[date] = memo[date] || {};
   memo[date][type] = parseInt(value);
   types.add(type);
   return memo;
 }, {});
 types = [...types];

 const data = Object.entries(rawObj).reduce((memo, [date, value]) => {
   memo.push([date, ...types.map(type => value[type] || 0)]);
   return memo;
 }, [['Billdate', ...types.map(type => `${type[0]}${type.substr(1).toLowerCase()}`)]]);

 
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     function drawChart() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

       var options = {
         title: 'Outlet Wise Sales',
         legend: { position: 'bottom',},
         hAxis: {title: 'Billdate',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}},
          pointSize: 7,
         vAxis: {title: 'Quantity',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}}
       };

       var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
</script>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

So what i am trying to achieve is that getting the Data from back-end and format it in the way i want to render the chart.

I  am doing the right thing by creating a new function `formatData` and  storing all data individually but don't know what to do next.

any one out there please help me out, i have provided both the J SON the on which i am getting from back-end and the one i want to be as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the transform you need:

```js
const raw =      [
      [
        "JAYANAGAR",
        "2018-09-01",
        "476426"
      ],
      [
        "MALLESHWARAM",
        "2018-09-01",
        "92141"
      ],
      [
        "KOLAR",
        "2018-09-01",
        "115313"
      ],
      [
        "JAYANAGAR",
        "2018-09-02",
        "511153"
      ],
      [
        "MALLESHWARAM",
        "2018-09-02",
        "115704"
      ],
      [
        "KOLAR",
        "2018-09-02",
        "83597"
      ],
      [
        "JAYANAGAR",
        "2018-09-03",
        "167421"
      ],
      [
        "KOLAR",
        "2018-09-03",
        "53775"
      ]
    ]
let types = new Set();
const rawObj= raw.reduce((memo, [type, date, value]) => {
  date = date.split('-').reverse().join('-');
  memo[date] = memo[date] || {};
  memo[date][type] = parseInt(value);
  types.add(type);
  return memo;
}, {});
types = [...types];

const data = Object.entries(rawObj).reduce((memo, [date, value]) => {
  memo.push([date, ...types.map(type => value[type] || 0)]);
  return memo;
}, [['Billdate', ...types.map(type => `${type[0]}${type.substr(1).toLowerCase()}`)]]);

console.log(data)
```